# Exact couples (section 14 of Bott Tu book "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology")

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, spectral-sequences, filtrations

In section 14, an exact couple,
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
A\overset{i}\longrightarrow A'\\
k\nwarrow\quad\swarrow j\\
  B
\end{array}
\end{equation}
is introduced.

I have a question about the map $i$.
Is it an inclusion?
$i:A\hookrightarrow A'$.I

I also would like to ask follows:
Here the author defined the map $d := j\circ k$ and says
$d^2 = j(kj)k = 0$.
Does the last equality follow from the exactness of the sequence?:
($\text{im}j = \ker k$).
\begin{equation}
\cdots\rightarrow 
A\overset{i}\rightarrow A'\overset{j}\rightarrow B
\overset{k}\rightarrow A\overset{i}\rightarrow\cdots
\end{equation}
Is the first triangle diagram a rewritten of this exact sequence?
If so, I would like to ask why this definition is useful and its motivation.

Comment: It is probably a typo : you should have $A=A'$ here. You indeed have $kj=0$ by exactness. And yes, the triangle can be rewritten as a long exact sequence $...\to A\xrightarrow{i}A\xrightarrow{j}B\xrightarrow{k}A\xrightarrow{i}A\to...$. As for the last question, this definition is useful to construct spectral sequences as the following of section 14 suggests.

Comment: Thank you! :D
The author says this triangle is "an exact sequence of Abelian groups."
I think this means A and B are Abelian groups. Is it needed to be  imposed this condition and what happed if we omit this condition?

Comment: The notion of exact couple exists in any abelian category, in particular in any categories of modules over a fixed ring. It makes no sense in other categories (what is an exact sequence of sets ?)

Comment: The author should have defined $d = j \circ k$. That's the real definition. You probably just misread or made a typo.

Comment: I made a mistake. The definition was $d:=j\circ k$ as written in the text.

Comment: And no $i$ doesn't have to be an inclusion, it can be zero if $k$ and $j$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: @NoelLundström thank you!

Comment: Why do we have to consider two A's? 
If we simply set $A\underset{k}{\overset{j}\rightleftarrows} B$, it does not make sense?